# Hi, I would like to ask, I used r program to fix my randmom multivariate multilevel models. but the funtion error, Could you give solution this

Tags: r

```
#error
MVMM2.2 <- lme(MUTU ~ - 1 + Respon+Respon:(x2+x4+x5+x9+x10+z1+z2+z3+x2*z1+x2*z2),
                random = ~ -1 + Respon:(x2 + x4) + Respon|kab.kota, 
                weights=varIdent(form=~1|Respon),
                corr=corSymm(form=~as.numeric(Respon)|kab.kota/npsn),
                data=data_edit, method="ML",
                control = list(maxIter=2380, msMaxIter=2380, tolerance=1e-8,
                              niterEM=1850))

Error
Error in lme.formula(MUTU ~ -1 + Respon + Respon:(x2 + x4 + x5 + x9   : 
  nlminb problem, convergence error code = 1
  message = singular convergence (7)
```

Comment: The error messager suggests that your data (which you haven't shown us) result in a model which is singular.  In other words at least one of your predictors can be constructed as a linear combination of the others.